# how to trace how a form is built

Tags: 7

I'm not too new to Drupal and working on modifying a module.. but I'm trying to figure out how a module builds it's form.
But can't seem to figure out how it's built. What methods can I use to trace it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "module builds it's form". Which form do you try to modify? A module builds its form normaly with the form api. So there must be a call with drupal_get_form (or system_settings_form in case of a settings form) somewhere in the module.